# install jdk on Ubuntu with rpm package

Tags: software-installation, deb, jdk, rpm, alien

I downloaded `jdk-8u73-linux-x64.rpm` from Oracle. then I try to convert `.rpm` to `.deb` to install it on Ubuntu 15.10. So I tried this code:

```
sudo alien jdk*.rpm
```

and after a few minutes I have `jdk1.8.0-73_1.8.073-1_amd64.deb` and a folder named `jdk1.8.0_73-1.8.0_73`

Then I try to install my new `.deb` package.

```
sudo dpkg -i jdk1.8.0-73_1.8.073-1_amd64.deb
```

I faced with this message:

```
(Reading database ... 213050 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jdk1.8.0-73_1.8.073-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking jdk1.8.0-73 (1.8.073-1) over (1.8.073-1) ...
Setting up jdk1.8.0-73 (1.8.073-1) ...
```

It seemed to install correctly. But when I tried to install Netbeans It said that:

```
Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: That's not the way to install it. There's a PPA containing Oracle's JDK and the alternative OpenJDK in the repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Oracle's Java Development Kit (Oracle JDK) from the **webupd8** PPA by running the commands below from a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This will add their PPA to your software sources, update your software index and then install their currently latest build of the Oracle JDK 8. At the date of writing, this should be *version 8u74*.

The advantages of this approach over your attempt to convert an rpm package are that the binaries were specifically built for your Ubuntu version and that the package manager will automatically handle updates.

---

If there's no special reason to use Oracle JDK, you can also just use the open source implementation, the OpenJDK 8 JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Differences between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK include that OpenJDK might miss some rarely used proprietary multimedia libraries and that it does not come with a web applet launcher by default. This functionality is outsourced and available under the name `icedtea`. Unfortunately there's no `icedtea-8-plugin` in the official repositories yet, so if you need to run Java web applets, you must install another PPA to get `icedtea-8-plugin` if you go for OpenJDK. If you never use Java web applets, there's absolutely no need for that plugin though.